# document.querySelector via textContent

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible in JS to select the first element whatsoever with `document.querySelector` solely by a given textDocument, if the that `textDocument` is available on viewport when the code is executed?

---

I am looking for a way **without** the following code because it brings out all relevant tagNames and **filters** them via textContent, but I want to **select** them by text content, not to filter.

```
document.querySelectorAll('tagName').forEach( (e)=>{
    if (e.textContent.includes('Delete')) {
        e.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to write shorter code, like `$("tagName:contains(Delete)").click()` in jQuery, or are you concerned about performance when filtering by content yourself? (I would think even if `.querySelectorAll()` directly supported this behind the scenes it would still need to iterate over all the elements of the specified type.)

Comment: Hmm, I just want JS to make a search like I do with `CTRL+F` and use the first element with the exact `textContent` it supplied, and then work with it... If it is being done, I couldn't care less from code longevity or performance. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is no [CSS selector targeting on textContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text).

Also, as your code is currently written, it's quite easy to grab the *first element which `textContent` `includes` this string*, it will always be `document.documentElement` or `null`.

You should make your query a bit more strict.

You could probably build an [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) query to this very extent, but that would end up slower than iterating over all the nodes by yourself.

So if performance is an issue, a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) is the way to go.

Here is a function that will grab elements by `textContent`.
It has different optional arguments which will allow you to tell

- if the query should be strict ("string === textContent" which is the default),
- a node to start the search from (defaults to `document.documentElement`)
- if you are only interested in the elements without children

```js
function getElementByTextContent(str, partial, parentNode, onlyLast) {
  var filter = function(elem) {
    var isLast = onlyLast ? !elem.children.length : true;
    var contains = partial ? elem.textContent.indexOf(str) > -1 :
      elem.textContent === str;
    if (isLast && contains)
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  };
  filter.acceptNode = filter; // for IE
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    parentNode || document.documentElement,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
      acceptNode: filter
    },
    false
  );
  var nodeList = [];
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
  return nodeList;
}
// only the elements whose textContent is exactly the string
console.log('strict', getElementByTextContent('This should be found'))
// all elements whose textContent contain the string (your code)
console.log('partial', getElementByTextContent('This should', true))
// only the elements whose textContent is exactly the string and which are the last Element of the tree
console.log('strict onlyLast', getElementByTextContent('This should be found', false, null, true))
```

```html
<p><span>This should be found</span></p>
<span>This should only in partial mode</span><br>
<span>This must not be found</span>
<!-- p should not be found in onlyLast mode -->
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. `document.querySelector` can only accept a string argument that describes one or more CSS selectors separated by commas. You cannot provide `document.querySelector` a `textDocument`.

You will have to check the content of a node different, with one way being the way you've described in the question.

Comment: Same answer. You cannot select them by text content. Your current approach is the right approach. :) I wish it could be shorter, but as @nnnnnn states _I would think even if .querySelectorAll() directly supported this it would still need to iterate over all the elements behind the scenes._